# To create a SAS code analyser utility

Tags: logic, sas

Apologies if this is a fancy question.

Is it possible to create a  utility that can process the code line by line and depicts its logic as a form of output.I am using SAS language and needs to read a whole lot of codes and understand and note its logic.I was wondering if there was a logic analyzer utility ,it would have helped dramatically.

Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: Do you intend to write such a tool, if it doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Yes...i dont know where to start....need your valuable inputs if any..:)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I think PROC SCAPROC does what you are looking for.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/64787/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0sf63lx4fs2m5n14qv1bn8p863v.htm

This can be used with SAS Enterprise Guide to build a custom flow to visualize the processing.  http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/311-2013.pdf

Comment: Yes! This is _exactly_ what Enterprise Guide is for--process flow!